# Why does updating a video's privacy status disable comments?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I noticed recently when updating a video's privacy setting via the YouTube API comments are disabled.  I was able to reproduce the problem using the API Explorer [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update#try-it).  I set an unlisted video to public and the comments are disabled.

I also tried the following combinations, all result in disabled comments

public -> private

private -> unlisted

unlisted -> public

public -> unlisted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug has been fixed on YT's end.